# EDIFACT How to group, spilt, sort and sum up values from a EDI string into variables in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string, group-by, split

I am new to VB.Net 2008. I have a tricky task to resolve, it is regarding extracting characters (values) from a long string, the extracted values from the text shall be summed up and sorted by keywords, reformatted and saved into a CSV file.

It looks something like this but much longer :

```
UNH+RAM6957'COMPANY1BY500C10'ZEW+REQEST6957'COMPANY2SL200C20'COMPANY1SL300C10'ZEW
```

The values are seperated by ' .

As first step I splitted the string to make it readable, I used the function like:

```
Dim LineOfText As String
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim aryTextFile() As String

    LineOfText = p_EDI
    aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split("'")

      For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)
        Console.WriteLine((aryTextFile(i)))
      Next i
```

Now the result looks like:

```
UNB+UNOA:1+CCP:ZEW+STE:ZEW+100901:1200+2010917283
UNH+M000001+ORDRSP:D:96A:UN:EGT102
BGM+02G::ZEW+NOMRES24364+34
DTM+Z05:0:805
DTM+137:201009011000:203
DTM+Z01:201009090400201009100400:719
RFF+AHI:GSCOMPANY1
NAD+ZSO+CCP::ZEW
NAD+ZSH+GSSTATKRAFT::ZEW
TDT+41G++70
LOC+Z11+:::TTF
LIN+1+23
LOC+Z11+:::TTF
QTY+Z05:0:KW1
DTM+2:201009090400201009100400:719
NAD+ZUS+GSBNP::ZEW
LIN+2+23
LOC+Z11+:::TTF
QTY+Z05:0:KW1
DTM+2:201009090400201009100400:719
NAD+ZUS+GSBPA::ZEW
```

So far so good:

Now I have to extract the date and time from the **header**:
The line looks like:

```
**DTM+137**:201009011000:203 should look like
DTM+137:2010.09.01-10:00:203 and store it into a 'incomming_DTM' variable for example
```

Now the **message period** would be interresting to know:
The line looke like:

```
**DTM+Z01**:201009090400201009100400:719 the output should look like:
DTM+Z01 2010.09.09-04:00, 2010.09.10-04:00 and store it into 'period_DTM' variable
```

As next step I need to parse the next lines until it reaches the **KEYWORD LIN**
Like:

```
LIN+1+23
LOC+Z11+:::TTF
QTY+Z05:0:KW1
DTM+2:201009090400201009100400:719
NAD+ZUS+GSBNP::ZEW
NAD+ZSH+COMPANY1RPH N001::ZEW (P Character in word -> SELL QTY:0 KW/h)

LIN+2+23
LOC+Z11+:::TTF
QTY+Z05:0:KW1
DTM+2:201009090400201009100400:719
NAD+ZUS+GSBPA::ZEW
NAD+ZSH+COMPANY1RRH N001::ZEW (R Character in word -> BUY QTY:0 KW/h)
```

and store the `KEYWORDS "QTY" "DTM" "NAD+ZSH"` and its following Characters
into variables.

THEN I need to parse until it reaches the next **LIN** Keyword and store the
keywords there into vaiables again. The goal of this complicated exercise is,
to sum up values of **QTY** and **NAD+ZSH+COMPANY1RVH** and **NAD+ZSH+COMPANY1RPH**

If we have a closer look at the last zwo charaters in **COMPANY1RRH** and **COMPANY1RPH**
we see **RH** and **PH**, RH means **buy** and PH means **sell**.
Maybe it is possible to store **BUY** or **SELL** into a Contract vaiable for each **LIN?**

I need to sum up all **sells** and **buys** which where found in the string.
Every **LIN** marks a time period of one hour, so we have probably 24 series per
string which contains 24 LIN every LIN have a Time period, BUY or SELL keywords
and a Quantity.

Can someone please help me with this task?

As first step, storing the keywords and its follwoing characters into variables would
be a very good start. It might be very good to do that probably until the parser reaches the `LIN`, then store the found values into a CSV file or Array?, then parse until the next LIN and so on...

I would like to create a CSV file out of the results like: So the CSV should contain
24 records one per every hour per every LIN..

```
Dim csvData = Now & "," & "TRADED_QTY" & "," & DTM+Z01 & "," & "N" & "," & QTY & "," & "KWH/h" & "," & Contract

Console.WriteLine(csvData)
 Creating the CSV File with True Flag -> Append data to CSV.
   Dim csvFile As String = "C:\Test.csv"
     Dim outFile As IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(csvFile, True)
```

Any ideas are highly welcome, I consider this as very complex task
espacial as I am really new to VB.NET.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I see "EDI" in your code. If this is an EDI format, then you should have, or be able to get, some kind of EDI specification. Likely, it will be a fixed-length specification, meaning that "Value X is characters 1 to 9", "Value Y is characters 10 to 11", "Value Z is character 12", etc.

Comment: Agreed with @HardCode. EDI files have fixed-length fields. You should be able to get specs for the file and parse easily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach to parse out the KEYWORDS as first step:

```
 Dim EDI As Object
    EDI = dataReader(0)
    'Convert EDI Object into a string and write it to the console.

    Dim p_EDI As String = Convert.ToString(EDI)

    'Create LineBreaks after every " ' "
    Dim LineOfText As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aryTextFile() As String

    LineOfText = p_EDI
      aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split("'")

    'Starting with IF clause to find keywords
      For Each line As String In aryTextFile
       Console.WriteLine(line)
         If line.StartsWith("UNB") Then
           Dim foundUNB_Data = p_EDI.IndexOf("UNB")
   'Start at that position and extract UNB + 27 characters 
                      Dim UNBData = EDI.Substring(foundUNB_Data, 30)
                      Console.WriteLine(UNBData)


  ElseIf line.StartsWith("LIN") Then
     .
      .

        ElseIf line.StartsWith("QTY") Then
          .
            .
            End If
                Next
```

Any further ideas are highly welcome..
Thank you.